# Update disabled Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

From what I know about Chrome extensions, if you have installed and enabled extension in Chrome, and there is a new version on Chrome Web Store that requires new permissions, Chrome will download new version and install it but the extension will be disabled and user will be prompt to evaluate new permissions and re-enable extension.

I am wondering what will happen if in the meantime, new, second update is published on store, that does not require the new permissions and the user has not yet re-evaluated previous update, so the extension is still disabled. Will the new update with the same permission set as before cause that Chrome automatically re-enables extension ?

Comment: i also wandered the same but afraid to try it on my live one and lazy to create an extension just to test this.

Comment: I will try it and let you you know how it behaves.

Comment: @ZigMandel Just an update, it looks like Chrome automatically enables extension in this case.

Comment: Feel free to post an "answer to your own question" and accept it, as it were...